# To read the json as a string object in android

Tags: java, android, json

I have read JSON data from a URL as a string object and passed it (as a string object) to my second activity. How can I read values from this string object? Please help me.

Below is my json:

```
{
    "speciality": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "d_name": "Dr.Steven Cohen",
            "file_upload": "dr-photo.png",
            "d_address": "3838 California St. San Francisco,CA 94118",
            "d_specialty": "Eye",
            "designation": "Ophthalmologist",
            "d_city": "San Francisco",
            "d_state": "Calfornia",
            "d_zipcode": "CA94118",
            "d_phone": "018  000  000",
            "latitude": "18.815427",
            "longitude": "76.775144"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "d_name": "Dr.  Hanish Patel",
            "file_upload": "hanish-patel.jpg",
            "d_address": " 160  East 56th Street New York, NY 10022 ",
            "d_specialty": "Eye",
            "designation": "Optometrist",
            "d_city": "New York",
            "d_state": "United States",
            "d_zipcode": "NY 10022",
            "d_phone": "018 000 000",
            "latitude": "40.760407",
            "longitude": "-73.968694"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "d_name": " Dr. Leonard Bley MD, FACS ",
            "file_upload": "leonard-bley.jpg",
            "d_address": " 160 East 56th Street New York, NY 10022",
            "d_specialty": "Eye",
            "designation": "Ophthalmologist",
            "d_city": "New York",
            "d_state": "United States",
            "d_zipcode": "NY 10022",
            "d_phone": "018 000 000",
            "latitude": "40.760407",
            "longitude": "-73.968694"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "d_name": "Dr. John Selle",
            "file_upload": "john_selle.jpg",
            "d_address": "2250 Hayes St Ste 206 San Francisco, CA 94117",
            "d_specialty": "Eye",
            "designation": "General  Practitioner",
            "d_city": "San Francisco",
            "d_state": "Calfornia",
            "d_zipcode": "CA94118",
            "d_phone": "018 000 000",
            "latitude": "37.78604",
            "longitude": "-122.457639"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my code:

```
try {
    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(strjson);
    //JSONObject uniObject =         mainObject.getJSONObject("speciality");
    //JSONObject  uniName = uniObject.getJSONObject("d_name");
    //JSONObject uniURL = uniObject.getJSONObject("d_address");

    JSONObject oneObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("d_name");

    Log.e("name:", "unique name" + oneObject);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Doesn't look wrong, what's not working with your code?

Comment: on log cat print the error org.json.JSONEXception:no value for id d_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ....

```
      JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(strjson);

      JSONArray Array = mainObject.getJSONArray("speciality");
        for (int j = 0; j < Array.length(); j++) 
        {   
            if (Array.getJSONObject(j).has("id")) 
            {
                String str1 = (Array.getJSONObject(j).getString("id"));
                String str2 = (Array.getJSONObject(j).getString("d_name"));
              Log.e("TA","name:"+str2);
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine but there is one problem; you assuming that **d_name** is a key in the main JSONObject.

You first need to get value for the key **speciality**; and then try to get **d_name** value.
Remember that response of getting **speciality** is JSONArray.

Comment: JSONObject oneObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("speciality");
    JSONObject  uniName = oneObject.getJSONObject("d_name");  getting the error at speciality of type org.json.JSONArray can not be converted to JSONObject

Comment: thats not the proper way to do; check API; you need to read into JSONArray and then can read specific value from JSONArray into JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
JSONArray Array = statusObject.getJSONArray("speciality");
            for (int j = 0; j < Array.length(); j++) 
            {   
                if (Array.getJSONObject(j).has("id")) 
                {
                    String str1 = (Array.getJSONObject(j).getString("id"));
                    String str2 = (Array.getJSONObject(j).getString("d_name"));
.
.
.
.
.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I hope this will be help to you...

```
  JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(strjson);
 JSONArray details= mainObject .getJSONArray("speciality");
 if (details.length()!=0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {

    String id = details.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

        String name = details.getJSONObject(i).getString("d_name");
                            ......
                            ......
            String longitude= friends.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude");
}
}
```